# A simple ajax question about IE8, Firefox3.6 and Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax

Javascript Code:

```
var httprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var time = new Date();
if (httprequest) {
  httprequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (httprequest.readyState == 4) {
      alert("OK");
    }
  };
  httprequest.open("GET", "http://www.google.com", false);
  httprequest.send(null);
}
alert(new Date() - time);
```

IE8: OK,time dialog will be prompt
Chrome10: OK dialog prompted, but time dialog do not be prompt
Firefox3.6: OK, time dialog will not be prompt

Why some dialog not to be prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

httprequest.send(null) in your case doesn't return at all - it blocks js code execution, so anything after that line doesn't get executed - I can't tell you why it does that, it might be  specifics of implementation on a particular browser or something else.

What you want to do here is to run it asynchronously: change "false" to "true" when calling "open" method:

```
httprequest.open("GET", "http://www.google.com", true);
```

On a related note - if you are to start playing with ajax, try some javascript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - they do a great job of making your life easier as a js developer providing browser-neutral methods for dealing with DOM, events, ajax and more.

Comment: Thank you! The reason of blocks is false paramter of open method.

Comment: I want to calc the time of this ajax request and want to synchronous. Set this paramter to true will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings maxima 
Your Code is ok and the answer of Andrey is great i have 2 notes :)

1- XMLHttpRequest Cant Do Request in out side of your domain if you need to request a page out side the domain do it server side .

2- in Andrey note to flee to jquery i am sorry i am not with him in that you should learn every thing about JavaScript first to be a pro then play with jquery with a complete under standing of what jquery do , my openion to be not a user for some library not before being a JavaScript pro

Comment: 1. Thanks for remind of across origin. 
2. I tryed jQuery library, jQuery has do many things for users.